# How to combine column using case condition in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a below table

| id | name | addr 1 | addr 2 | EXTRA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | US | RED |  |
| 1 | bbb | IN | IN | YELLOW |
| 1 | ccc | US | RED |  |
| 1 | ccc | IN | IN | ORANGE |
| 1 | ccc | EU | GREEN |  |

as depicted in above table, u can see that i want to bring IN value of EXTRA col into addr2 column overriding the value in addr2. i want to apply case condition or decode to achieve this.

| id | name | addr 1 | addr 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | US | RED |
| 1 | bbb | IN | YELLOW |
| 1 | ccc | US | RED |
| 1 | ccc | IN | ORANGE |
| 1 | ccc | EU | GREEN |

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to "apply case condition or decode to achieve this"? Why do you care **how** the problem is solved? Case expression or decode are just some tools available to you; usually a problem statement does not require what tools must be used. You may have a good reason to do this unusual thing; but if you do have a good reason, you didn't share it with us.

Comment: Note also that SQL has case **expressions**. PL/SQL (but not SQL) also has something called "case **statements**" - totally irrelevant to your question anyway. There is no such thing as case **condition**, either in SQL or in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use `coalesce()`:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(extra, addr2) as new_addr2
from t;
```

If you want to change the data in the table, then use `update`:

```
update t
    set addr = extra
    where extra is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this on your select statement you can use following one:

```
select  id
        , name
        , addr1
        , case when EXTRA IS NULL THEN addr2 ELSE EXTRA END as addr2
from    tablename
;
```

If you want to change date in table then you can use:

```
update tablename
set addr2 = EXTRA
where EXTRA is not null;
```

Comment: I don't think so; "IN" (from my point of view) represents "India", so you'd have to decode virtually all countries in the world to make that code work. COALESCE is a way to go (again, from my point of view).

Comment: I'm agreed with you but question asked for decode and case to achieve this problem. He also can use case with null condition for achieve that problem. I will update my comment. Thanks for you attention. Good point.